# What is proton leak?

Tags: cell-biology, mitochondria

I have some idea about it. Is it the wasteful back flow of H+ ions through uncoupling proteins during aerobic respiration?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.  It also includes unspecific leakage without the aid of uncoupling proteins, since the mitochondrial inner membrane is not entirely impermeable to protons. For example, protons might fall backward through the proton-pumping complexes, through other solute carriers, or through other openings or irregularities in the membrane.